# Create index for this condition using data.table

Tags: r, data.table

how to get the startdate and enddate(cumulative) from days

```
      Variable A  days  stardate  enddate(cumulative) 
          A        2       0           2
          A        3       2           5
          B        4       5           9
          A        3       0           3
          B        8       3          11
```

Comment: I'm guessing you want to do this with actual dates? Please confirm.

Comment: Your question started out vague and became vaguer.. This above is your desired output, at least that is my assumption. However, you can't get a startdate of 0 on row 1 when you take day 4 (row 3) and subtract day 2(row1). Rephrase your question.

Answer (score 1):

Using a combination of `cumsum` and `shift`:

```
dt1[, grp := cumsum(shift(Variable, fill='A')=='B')
    ][, startdate := cumsum(shift(days, fill = 0)), grp
      ][, enddate := startdate + days][]
```

which gives:

```
> dt1
   Variable days grp startdate enddate
1:        A    2   0         0       2
2:        A    3   0         2       5
3:        B    4   0         5       9
4:        A    3   1         0       3
5:        B    8   1         3      11
```

---

Used data:

```
dt1 <- data.table(Variable = c("A","A","B","A","B"), days = c(2,3,4,3,8))
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you want the days + the startdate to be in the enddate column. Then you can simply use this:

```
df <- data.table(Variable=c("A", "A", "B", "A", "B"), days=c(2,3,4,3,8), startdate=c(0,2,5,9,12), enddate=c(0))
df$enddate <- as.numeric(df$days + df$startdate)
```

Comment: not exactly, only there is variables A and days to get startdate and endate

Comment: @DFR How are you supposed to calculate a numeric value or Date time when having an alphabetic categorical value and an integer. Can you explain more thoroughly? The table in your question, is that the desired output, or input? Can you show me what you mean exactly by updating your question?

Comment: my mistake,  it is always start at A  then end at B as a block to compute startdate and enddate

Comment: @DFR So you want the span from A to B? Is days the day it started on, or the amount of days used? It makes more sense if it is the day it started on I think? So then A started on day 2 in row 1, and started on day 3 again in row 2. Both row 1 and 2 end in row 3? So Row 1 took 4 -2 days, and row 2 took 4 -3 days? Do I understand you correctly?

Comment: cumulate days for span A to B. so on so forth